# Why I can't show pictures which I have added into source file in Qt 5.9?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I am studying Qt 5.9 by "C++ GUI programming cookbook", but I can't load images.I am very confused and I have tried to search the answer but didn't find any.

I have put all pictures into the source file

[image]

The pictures can be displayed in the IDE.

[image]

But I can't find the image after compiling

Comment: I'm so sorry that I can't upload more than two pictures about the details.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please take some time to read [help], especially the sections named [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask]. Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by _I can't find the image after compiling_?

Answer (score 1):

You defined your images in a .qrc file. Those images will be put into your executable after compiling. Hence you won't find them in the directory.

Best regards